# Sending data from Android to a PHP server

Tags: android, android-location

I am having an application in android and I want to send the latitude and longitude of the android mobile to the web PHP server through a url (`like=..mydata.php?lat=76867&long=87979`). I am having the php code that saves the data in database if this url is hit.

All I am not getting is that how to send the latitude and longitude through my android mobile phone to the PHP server.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon @DarkXphenomenon answer, make sure you have the right permissions.

```
// to retrieve location
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
// to retrieve location
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
// to send data
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then in your java class you can use this code to send the data to the php file. Make sure to catch any exceptions.

```
String and = "&";

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://my site.com/gpsdata.php?imei="+imei+and+"lat="+lat+and+"lng="+lng+and+"alt="+alt+and+"spd="+speed);

        try {

             httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d(TAG, "Data sent!");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Client protokol exception ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "IO exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
```

You also need to make sure that your location variables such as latitude or longitude are strings otherwise you will get some unexpected errors. Normally the location variables would be a double or a float. To convert a double to a string, excecute

```
String Longitude = Double.toString(doubleToConvertToString);
```

And likewise a Float to a String

```
String Longitude = Float.toString(doubleToConvertToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The manifest needs to contain

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
```

**Update:**
Network connections are no longer allowed in the UI thread. You need to then issue an HTTP get wrapped in an [`AsyncTask<>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which will be parsed and interpreted by your PHP backend.
An example  is at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: I am already having the latitude and longitude but in the second answer 'run on separate thread' is important?? and where to write my URL??

Comment: See edited answer. You need to run it on a different thread if you don't want the HTTP request and response to block the main thread.

Comment: sorry but i am not getting the values in my database.

Comment: Try reading the String `response`, to check if the webpage responded correctly. Also, check your manifest to see if `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` exists.

Comment: Why did you protect the question? Doesn't seem like it really needs it :)