# Sending data with Android to server

Tags: java, android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

I need a simple Android function that sends a JSON object to an IP address that is saved in the preferences of the phone.
Now, I know how to use prefs, I know how JSON works (theoretically), but I don't know how to actually send it to the server.

Note that, in this case, I don't actually care about security, encryption or anything else, just sending a simple JSON object with simple data such as "name", "latitude", "longitude", "time", "password".

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575591/how-to-send-send-data-from-android-to-php-server

Comment: This might help you, I've asked a different question but theres code to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665331/java-server-client-socket-communication

Comment: check this one [Client Server Communication Using Json in android](https://github.com/OsamaShabrez/ClientServerJSON) & here is a complete explaination about this code http://osamashabrez.com/client-server-communication-android-json/#respond

Answer (score 0):

example...
if your web service http url follow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863521.aspx

then enter data as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863521.aspx?name="abc"

i hope this one help you, if use .net web service